# How to resolve DependencyResolutionManagement warning in Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I created a new Android project using Android Studio version - **Electric Eel**. And I was trying to migrate gradle scripts from `groovy` to `kotlin DSL`, met warnings.

In last project developed on previous version of Android Studio - **Chipmunk**, script was clean. The scripts between last project and new project are equal.

I want to remove the warning message in the right way not supressing them. I know what the annotation(`@Incubating`) means.

Here's the `settings.gradle.kts`.  
*Comments* are the warnings I encountered.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    // 'getRepositoriesMode()' is declared in unstable interface 'org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.DependencyResolutionManagement' marked with @Incubating 
    // 'org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode' is marked unstable with @Incubating 
    // 'FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS' is declared in unstable enum 'org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode' marked with @Incubating 
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

    // 'repositories(org.gradle.api.Action<? super org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler>)' is declared in unstable interface 'org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.DependencyResolutionManagement' marked with @Incubating 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyNewProject"
include(":app")
```

My IDE, gradle, agp versions:

- IDE: **Electric Eel (2022.1.1, Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386)**

> Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1  
> Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023  
> Runtime version: 11.0.16+8-b2043.64 amd64  
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.  
> Windows 10 10.0  
> GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation

- Gradle: **7.5**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

- agp: **7.4.0**

(in `build.gradle`, which is still with `groovy`)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: I continued migrating other build scripts to kotlin DSL, I met many classes, methods highlighted warning `@Incubating`. (ex. `isMinifyEnabled`, `compose`, and so on)

Comment: This happens to me as well when switching to Gragle Kotlin DSL. Is it really possible that Google made so many Gradle features unstable in Kotlin DSL (all those were just fine in Groovy)???

Answer (score 2):

Add  @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage") to fix temporarily problem in the interested code like

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. I finally added `@Suppress` annotation. You can see the my self-answer below. I wish they release stable version in a short time..

Answer (score 0):

I double checked the **Inspection settings** both IDE versions, *Unstable API Usage* options are all enabled. The options includes correct annotation - `org.gradle.api.incubating`.

I think electric eel version resolves a bug(Actucally I'm not sure), but this is not resolved clearly, until they release it stable API or other way...

For now I added `@file:Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")` at the top of each gradle script.

[image: Settings-Editor-Inspections-Unstable-API-Usage]